# How do I create a custom JSON 401 page for my Spring MVC/Security restful web service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to create a secured restful web service using Servlet 3.0, Spring MVC and Spring Security. I'd like to return a custom JSON message on a 401 instead of the default HTML message returned by the Servlet container.

I've tried several approaches but can't seem to get this working.

My controller looks like follows::

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ApplicationController {

    private ApplicationFactory applicationFactory;

    @Inject
    public ApplicationController(ApplicationFactory applicationFactory) {
        super();
        this.applicationFactory = applicationFactory;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    @ResponseBody
    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    public Application getApplicationInfo() {
        return applicationFactory.buildApplication(this);
    }

}
```

And my Spring Security context looks as follows:

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" mode="aspectj" />

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<security:http-basic />
</security:http>
```

I've tried adding the following:

```
@ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
@ResponseBody
public Application accessDenied() {
    return applicationFactory.buildApplication(this);
}
```

But it gets ignored. I've tried adding "access-denied-page="/denied"" to my security:http tag with the following in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/denied", method = GET)
@ResponseBody
public Application accessDenied() {
    return applicationFactory.buildApplication(this);
}
```

But it gets ignored. I've tried a custom access denied handler as follows:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<security:http-basic />
<security:access-denied-handler ref="jsonAccessDeniedHandler" />
</security:http>
```

The only thing that does seem to work is the following:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseBody
public Application accessDenied() {
    return applicationFactory.buildApplication(this);
}
```

But this catches everything and I only want to customise a failed authentication.

Lastly, adding this to my web.xml also works:

```
<error-page>
<error-code>401</error-code>
<location>/401</location>
</error-page>
```

But I'd prefer to configure as much pro-grammatically or through annotations.

Answer (score 4):

In spring 3.0 there is a annotation ResponseStatus

I use this annotation like this;

```
@ResponseStatus(value = 401)
@ExceptionHandler(value = HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorResponse handleJsonMappingException(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
```

Is this helpfull?

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't seem to work: spring security ignores the @ResponseStatus(UNAUTHORIZED) and  @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class) annotations. Is there any additional configuration I need?

Comment: Correction: using @ResponseStatus(UNAUTHORIZED) with @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class) worked with Spring Security 3.1.

Comment: humh thought so, it is a spring 3.1 feature (I am using spring 3.1.x)

Comment: Uh oh, just found out that the above solution doesn't add the WWW-Authenticate HTTP header to the 401 response so the client has no idea what realm to authenticate for and so, in my browser, doesn't prompt the user for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

To use @ResponseBody and manipulate the response header us the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = { "Accept=application/json" })
public @ResponseBody
List handle(HttpServletResponse response,
@RequestHeader("headerID") String headerString) {
response.setHeader("responseHeaderProperty", String);
return service.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: That is an alternative, but seems like breaking DRY when Spring Security is already handling the HTTP headers for me. BTW you can probably edit your original answer and copy-and-paste the above into that!

Comment: well I could add this to a comment (it is to big), and well this part doesn't reflect to your original question. But glad to help :X